# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 IOS 7

Tags: ios, armv7

Hi I'm trying to create route map in my application i got the some classes file to implement the route map so i have imported into my project after importing its giving this issue   showing error like this.

```
      Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
      "_uregex_end", referenced from:
      _rkl_performRegexOp in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_findRanges in RegexKitLite.o
     "_uregex_appendReplacement", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
     "_uregex_groupCount", referenced from:
     _rkl_getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
     "_uregex_appendTail", referenced from:
     _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
     "_u_strlen", referenced from:
    _rkl_userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
     "_uregex_reset", referenced from:
    _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
     "_uregex_close", referenced from:
    _rkl_clearCacheSlotRegex in RegexKitLite.o
     "_u_errorName", referenced from:
   _rkl_NSExceptionForRegex in RegexKitLite.o
   _rkl_userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
    "_uregex_findNext", referenced from:
   _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
   _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
    "_uregex_setText", referenced from:
   _rkl_clearCacheSlotSetTo in RegexKitLite.o
   _rkl_setCacheSlotToString in RegexKitLite.o
   "_uregex_start", referenced from:
  _rkl_performRegexOp in RegexKitLite.o
  _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
  _rkl_findRanges in RegexKitLite.o
   "_uregex_open", referenced from:
   _rkl_getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_find", referenced from:
   _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm getting error like this please tell me how to resolve this i have tried many solution its not working for me I have been stuck here for long time please help out to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed to add linker flag. Add it by below way.

```
"Build Settings"->"Linking"->"Other Linker Flags" add the flag as "-licucore"
```